# Why does Apache Airflow return execution_date = None?

Tags: airflow

I am interested in collecting the internal Airflow variable 'execution_date'. However, it returns None while in other dag tasks it works correctly.

Does anyone know why?

[image]

[image: airflow]

Answer (score 1):

Borja!

I can't tell where the error is sourced from because there's no context about this execution. The first thing to say is that whatever is getting passed through the `context` name as part of Python  `**kwargs` convention is not  what you are expecting.

You can tell this in part, because your `kwargs` collection will always be a `dictionary`, and as such has a `.get()` method, which will default and return `None` if the key is not present.

So in whatever context this function is called there are no extra keyword arguments with the name `execution_date`.

Which again is confirmed by the fact you don't use the variable anywhere else int his function. To try investigate, I'd have your system print or log the context as  a first step. Then work from there

---

My guess is what you are doing is using the `PythonOperator` to execute this callable `data_per_sheet`.

In which case there can only really be one source of this error. You need to  define your task  with `provide_context=True`.